# Snackbar doesn't react for snackbar.dismiss()

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I have a problem with snackbar. My snackbar doesn't react for dismiss

My code:

```
ConnectivityReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            ConnectivityManager cm =
                    (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                    .make(drawer, getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction(getResources().getString(R.string.settings), new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
                        }
                    });

            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                    activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

            if(!isConnected){
                snackbar.show();
            }else {
                snackbar.dismiss();
            }
        }
    };
```

I checked and my app is in else state if isConnected return true.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You try to dismiss a snackbar that is not showing, because you don't have a reference to the one that you've created earlier. 
Move the SnackBar declaration as a field of your class and it should work.

Comment: actually the OP *needs to* make it a class field and initialize it only once. Right now that is a local field